# catching error in GET request is retrieving Uncaught Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having some difficulties with checking the side scenario of an API request.
I have this component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
    getOrganizationByObjectId,
    updateOrganization
} from "../../../services/apiRequests";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {formStructure, yupValidation, defaultValue} from "../../../schemas/OrganizationSchemas.jsx";
import {UPDATE} from "../../../utils/definitions.jsx";
import FormEntity from "../../../components/FormEntity.jsx";
import Message from "../../../components/Message.jsx";
import {BeatLoader} from "react-spinners";

const EditOrganization = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(defaultValue());
    //const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
    const {objectId} = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        getOrganizationByObjectId(objectId)
            .then((response) => setValues(response))
            .catch((error) => {
                setErrorMsg(error.error);
            });
    }, [objectId]);

    const renderFormEntity = () => {
        if (errorMsg === "") {
            return (
                <FormEntity
                    formStructure={formStructure()}
                    yupValidation={yupValidation()}
                    submitMethod={updateOrganization}
                    title={"Edit Organization"}
                    values={values}
                    formType={UPDATE}
                    forwardToAfterRequest={'/organizations/list'}
                />
            );
        }
        return null;
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Message message={errorMsg} severity={"error"}/>
            {renderFormEntity()}
        </>
    );
};

export default EditOrganization;
```

On the first run, it should fetch the data from the server using the `useEffect()` hook.
while giving proper and valid ID, and no error has been caught by the hook everything works perfectly.

But when I deliver some wrong ID the server receives an exception, and the expectation from the code is to store it inside the state `errorMsg`.

- I have checked and error. the error.error has the correct value.

for some reason, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.
```

I have debugged the code, and the error is related to the state errorMsg when removing that `setErrorMsg()` the code is working perfectly but without the error message..

if the errorMsg is not empty I am generating the `Message` component:

```
const Message = ({message, severity}) => {
    return (
        message !== '' &&
        <Alert severity={severity} sx={{mt: 3, mb: 3, width: "100%"}}>
            <div style={{ marginRight: '20px' }}>{message}</div>
        </Alert>
    );
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: what do you believe `({message, severity}) => {` returns when `message` is empty string?

Comment: @JaromandaX, it should return anything I have the condition `message !== ""` for that validation

Comment: so, if message is NOT empty, it returns `<Alert ...` ... but if it IS empty, it returns what? hint, it returns boolean value `false` - I don't know enough about react to know if that's an issue. In your other code, you return `null` when the condition isn't met

Comment: I have changed the component to be more accurate, if message and severity is '' it will return null and the results are the same.

Comment: OK, as I said, don't know react well enough to know if that's an issue

Answer (score 0):

When using Functional Components in React, you need to take care that your code should contain same number of hooks regardless of your props or state.

So, doing something like

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("A");

  if (name === "B") {
    const [age, setAge] = useState(10);
  }

  return <div onClick={() => setName("B")}>Hello</div>;
}
```

will give an error any time the div is clicked. This is bacause, after clicking on the div, the `name` state was changes to **B**. This resulted in the if statement being executed where we called another hook for `[age, setAge]`.

In your code, I don't see this kind of code being written, so my best guess is that in your **renderFormEntity** method

```
const renderFormEntity = () => {
  if (errorMsg === "") {
    return (
      <FormEntity
        formStructure={formStructure()}
        yupValidation={yupValidation()}
        submitMethod={updateOrganization}
        title={"Edit Organization"}
        values={values}
        formType={UPDATE}
        forwardToAfterRequest={"/organizations/list"}
      />
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

where the `if` statement becomes true, the `formStructure` and `yupValidation` methods are called. I am guessing the `formStructure` method is actually a functional component containing some hooks.

If that is the case, there are 2 possible solutions you can use

1. Add a new prop called `hidden` to the `FormEntity` component and just hide the contents of the component while keeping all the hooks.

```
function FormEntity(props) {
  // place all your hooks and logic here
  
  if (props.hidden) {
    return null;
  }

  // return the JSX if this element is not hidden
}
```

2. Instead of passing `formStructure` by calling the method, check if `formStructure={<FormStructure />}` works